# 3D distance and topography

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, interpolation, proximity

I have a set of points and want to find out the nearest distance to a water body (poly lines) taking into account the terrain and get a surface distance calculation. I understand that the way is to use the interpolate shape tool to convert the 2d polylines into 3d polylines and then run the near 3d tool. The z values are coming from a DEM raster tile. Running it, the tool creates an empty feature class. 
Additionally I tried to use to drape the poly line feature class that contains the water body data over the DEM raster file using the base heights function from surface in the properties settings. But the setting are not being stored and the polylines maintain their 2d shape.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2

Comment: I think this question needs more precise details of what you have tried (tools and parameter values) before it is likely to attract a potential answerer.